# JavaScript Acces Object Prop

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

[image: this]

If I try to get the value from it by using `let result  = object.3h` I get the following error

[image: this]

```
error: `Parsing error: Identifier directly after number`.
```

Comment: Show the error and object (in literal form) in the question.

Comment: @Dominique Fortin done

Comment: How do you `console.log` that object in that image ? please add minimal example

Comment: Identifiers cant start with numbers. You will have to access the property by string key. `object['3h']`.

Comment: @AndreiShadowS Try `console.log( object['3h'] );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) in Javascript can’t start with a number (You can check the exact rules at the link provided.

When dealing with object properties, you can use string literals for defining properties that won’t follow this rule (Which might also happen when dealing with JSON objects)

In order to access this properties you need to use a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

On your case:

```js
day.rain[‘3h’]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use bracket notation

correct

```
object["3h"]
```

incorrect

```
object.3h
```

```js
    const object = { "3h": 0.44 }
    console.log(object["3h"])
```